# Malicious payload in raw media file content

Tags: malware, attack-prevention, attack-vector

As with anything to do with software, there have been many documented security vulnerabilities that relate to media files. While many of these exploits take advantage of attributes or variables of specific files types, such as metadata or comments associated with a file, my question is this:

Is it possible for a maliciously crafted media file (e.g. image or audio file) to contain its malicious payload not in the specific metadata of a file type but in the raw media data of the file itself, regardless of format?

For example, let's say that a malicious image file contains a specific sequence of pixels with specific RGB values that are parsed by an appropriate library and execute attacker code. Could this possibly constitute an attack vector?

Comment: Please specify "appropriate". Does this mean a specifically placed malicious library? Or just one with a known vulnerability? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> ...  that are parsed by an appropriate library

Can one create such an appropriate library which will look for payload inside arbitrary images (not only metadata), extract and execute it? Yes, this is possible.

Will a "normal" library behave this way? No, it will not. It might have specific vulnerabilities which can be triggered by interpreting the image in the wrong way, i.e. making wrong assumptions about needed buffer sizes, value of parameters in image etc. This is not only about metadata but about the encoded pixels themselves, especially if compression is involved - like in [CVE-2020-1895](https://research.checkpoint.com/2020/instagram_rce-code-execution-vulnerability-in-instagram-app-for-android-and-ios/).

But a universal vulnerability, which can be attacked regardless of image format, is very very unlikely to happen by accident. It could be part of a deliberately placed backdoor though. Or it could be a way to hide a more complex second stage payload which gets retrieved and executed by a small initial attack payload.

Answer (score 1):

Like Steffen Ullrich, I think that although specific vulnerabilities exist for specific file formats, and their interpreters, a general "image" or "video" vulnerability, which is based in the raw content, does not exist.

However, like in e.g. log4j, **the existence of an exploitable general "feature", which exists over multiple file formats, is conceivable.**

One such example might be an automatic QR code parser feature, which is used by various image or video libraries. In such a scenario, if it can be triggered without user interaction and downloads and maybe even executes malicious content, IMHO this would count as "Malicious payload in raw media file content".

---

A real life example of such an "exploit", with benign intent, is the "Privacy Playground initiative". They deliberately place visually obsctructed QR codes on playgrounds, with the intent of the phone camera opening a website with information about the dangers of sharing children's pictures online.

Read more about it here, in German, French, Italian only: https://www.kinderschutz.ch/eltern-und-erziehungsberechtigte/kinderbilder-im-netz